# In Japanese, what's the difference between 全て (subete) and 有らゆる (arayuru)

Tags: meaning, word-choice

全て (subete) [is defined as everything; all; the whole](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%A8%E3%81%A6)

有らゆる (arayuru) [is defined as all; every​](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%89%E3%82%86%E3%82%8B)

## Example phrases:

**One:**

繰り返しますが、小麦粉、あらゆる肉、魚を含まないものです。

kurikaeshimasu ga, komugi-ko, arayuru niku, sakana o fukumanai mono desu.

(Repeating, NO wheat flour, all the meat and fish, not containing these things.)

**Two:**

その すべて の うた お うたう こと が できます.

Sono subete no uta o utau koto ga dekimasu.

(I can sing the name of all 40 Sentai teams.)

---

Why does one use 全て (subete) and the other 有らゆる (arayuru)? Are they interchangeable?

---

*Please note: I am more concerned with the meaning and I am still learning Kana, so the Kana I have used might not be 100% correct.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

すべて is a simple word meaning "all ～" or "every ～". あらゆる has the nuance of "all kinds of ～", "every sort of ～" or "every ～ you can imagine". Etymologically, this ゆる in あらゆる means "possible".

For example すべての人 means "all the people (in the room, country, etc)", while あらゆる人 is closer to "all kinds of people (age, sex, nationality, ...)".

> - すべての肉
>     all the meat (e.g., in the fridge, in the store)
> - あらゆる肉
>     all kinds of meat (chicken, beef, pork, ...)
> - すべての歌を歌うことができます。
>     I can sing all the songs (e.g., in this list).
> - あらゆる歌を歌うことができます。
>     I can sing all sorts of songs. (e.g., hip-hop, opera, ...)
> - 世界のすべての国に行きました。
>     I went to all the countries in the world. (literally all the 197 countries)
> - 世界のあらゆる国に行きました。
>     I went to all kinds of countries in the world. (someone who has visited 50 different countries can safely say this)

あらゆる always modifies indefinite things. You can say すべての人 referring to "all *the* five people" you have already mentioned in a conversation, but you cannot say あらゆる人 in this situation. Also note that あらゆる is almost always written only in hiragana.